# color formatting excel copy to corresponding row

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to excel VBA and trying to prepared VBA addin:

Current situation: In our excel spreadsheet column A consistent of different financial line items and values punched in Column B and so on.

We have one internal tool which coloured all formula and numbers used in any tab. However, if we use the same tool to remove the colors it will also removed the original color applied in cell and make is white

I like to create VBA,which which will only copy color from column A and paste the same color (only color no other formatting) in column B,C, D so on.

I have created one VBA code which helps me to copy bold to different column, now instead of bold I want color to paste in different columns

```
Sub FilterBold()
    Dim myRange As Range
    On Error GoTo Canceled
    Set myRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select a Range", Title:="InputBox Method", Type:=8)
    myRange.Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each myRange In Selection
        If myRange.Font.Bold = True Then
            myRange.Columns("b:GR").Font.Bold = True
        End If
    Next myRange
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Canceled:
End Sub
```

Comment: Sub FilterBold()
Dim myRange As Range
On Error GoTo Canceled
Set myRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please Select a Range", Title:="InputBox Method", Type:=8)
myRange.Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each myRange In Selection
If myRange.Font.Bold = True Then
myRange.Columns("b:GR").Font.Bold = True
End If
Next myRange
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Canceled:
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all cells in column A (source col)has same color... otherwise it will give a black color to the target column(C)

```
Range("C:C").Interior.Color = Range("A:A").Interior.Color
```

update-1 col by col

```
Sub foo2()

Dim ARows, CRows As Long
Dim SourceRange, TargetRange As String

Dim SFirstRow, TfirstRow As Integer ' these are the starting points for the coluring of the col, in case you have header which is not colured.
SFirstRow = 2 ' if you have header which is to be ignored... otherwise make it 1 
TfirstRow = 2


 ARows = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 CRows = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

     SourceRange = "A" & SFirstRow & ":A" & ARows
     TargetRange = "C" & TfirstRow & ":C" & CRows

Range(TargetRange).Interior.Color = Range(SourceRange).Interior.Color



End Sub
```

update 2- to do it row by row

```
Sub foo2()

Dim ARows, CRows As Long
Dim SourceRange, TargetRange As String

Dim SFirstRow, indexS As Integer ' these the starting points for the coluring of the col, in case you have header which is not colured.
SFirstRow = 1



 ARows = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 CRows = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row



Application.ScreenUpdating = False



For indexS = SFirstRow To ARows Step 1

ActiveSheet.Range("B" & indexS).Interior.Color = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & indexS).Interior.Color
ActiveSheet.Range("C" & indexS).Interior.Color = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & indexS).Interior.Color
ActiveSheet.Range("D" & indexS).Interior.Color = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & indexS).Interior.Color

Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub`
```

update-3, This Code fetches the last column used in your excelsheet and colours from column B(can in changed) to the last used column you have in your sheet

```
Sub foo3()

Dim ATotalRows As Long
Dim SourceRange, TargetRange As String
Dim TargetSheet As Worksheet
Dim SFirstRow, SFirstCol, indexRows, indexCols, TotalCols As Long ' these the starting points for the coluring of the col, in case you have header which is not colured.


Set TargetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Enter The name of your worksheet here

SFirstRow = 1  ' The Row from where to start
SFirstCol = 2  ' The Column from where to start coloring, in this case from the second column- 'B'
SLastCol= 10 ' index number of last col to be colored


ATotalRows = TargetSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row





Application.ScreenUpdating = False



For indexRows = SFirstRow To ATotalRows Step 1
    For indexCols = SFirstCol To SLastCol Step 1 ' starts coluring form B
        TargetSheet.Cells(indexRows, indexCols).Interior.Color = TargetSheet.Range("A" & indexRows).Interior.Color
    Next
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True







End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, really appreciate your help "Update 2" worked really well... would it be possible to make  indexS = SFirstRow dynamic   as some time I have column more then 100

Comment: @satyaprakash code is totally dynamic, you just have to give the Row number from where to start, which can be done by assigning `SFirstRow` the row number, in this case, it will  start from Row 1, and
`ARows = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`
returns the last row number of column A where your last entry is, so the loop traverses from 'SFirstRow' (Starting Row ) up to the row where you have the last entry in Column A.

Comment: Ok do you want to color more columns then just `B`,`C` and `D`? in that case is the total no. of column(to be colored) is a fixed value or also variable?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes I have more column then B, C 7 D...would it be possible to make column number as  dynamic or based on user choice

Comment: @satyaprakash delete this line 
`TotalCols = TargetSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`

and un-comment the very next line to it... and assign your choise of number of columns 
i.e.  
`TotalCol = 10`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using this code:

```
Sub FilterColor()
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Set sh = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    LastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set myRange = sh.Range("A1:A" & LastRow)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each rng In myRange
        For i = 1 To 10
            rng.Offset(0, i).Interior.Color = rng.Interior.Color
        Next i
    Next rng

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This code has a dynamic range in column A, which loops for each cell in that range, then copy the color and paste in every column after that. The number of columns the code will paste is given by variable `i`. In this case, the code will paste the color format in the next 10 columns.

Remember to change this `.Sheets("Sheet1")` to the name of your sheet.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code, it really worked well, would it be possible to make myRange dynamic  "For i = 1 To 10", option to put number as some time I have column more then 100